# How to save django manytomany field without through table

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, manytomanyfield

I face a vicious cycle that I cannot break out of;

Lets say I have a following model:

```
class AgregatorProductCoupon(models.Model):
    AgregatorProductId = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="coupons", db_column='AgregatorProductId', verbose_name=_("Agregator Product Id"))

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'AgregatorProductCoupon'
```

when I try to save an instance, I get an integrity error stating

```
"<AgregatorProductCoupon: AgregatorProductCoupon object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

but when I try to save without the m2m rel, I obviously get an error for a required field missing.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AgregatorProductId', table 'test_dbo.dbo.AgregatorProductCoupon'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I cannot redesign the tables as they are bound to other places too.
How to go about it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Traceback:

```
[2021-01-07 13:19:28,040] log_response - Internal Server Error: /admin/agregator/agregatorcoupons/78/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1650, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1536, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1576, in _changeform_view
    self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1122, in save_related
    self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1110, in save_formset
    formset.save()
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 669, in save
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 803, in save_new_objects
    self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 949, in save_new
    obj.save()
  File "C:\David\agregator\models.py", line 2745, in save
    print(self.AgregatorProductId)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 526, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "C:\David\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 821, in __init__
    raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
ValueError: "<AgregatorProductCoupon: AgregatorProductCoupon object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: can you show your `Product` model?

Comment: It is a basic model, 

`Class Product(models.Model):
    name= models.Charfield(max_length=100)`
illustrates it perfectly

Comment: hmm, can you traceback why your AggregatorProductCoupon is None when you are trying to add products to the field? Looks like you are trying to add objects to a non existing coupon instance

Comment: That is exactly right - what it says is that the instance (which is none atm) hasn't been saved because of the m2m reason as far as I understand it

Comment: can you add your `views.py` or show the process of creating/updating the coupon?

Comment: I'm using django admin only for this, I edit it using a standart inline

`class ProductsToCouponsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    template = 'admin/agregator/agregatorcoupons/tabular-products.html'
    verbose_name = _('Related products')
    model = AgregatorProductCoupon
    extra = 3
    list_max_show_all = 10000
    list_per_page = 2000
    exclude = []
    fields = ['AgregatorProductId']`

Comment: try to first create an empty coupon object, save it, and then add products to it

Comment: I cant unfortunatelly do that, the m2m field is rquired

Comment: well you also cant save instances in many2many fields before the object is created so you'll have to set it to `Null` before this code can work properly